# Split results from DB for review in DC

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, discord.py

All entries for a user are pulled from a DB. These come then all quite unreadable after one another. Is it possible to write each row into a new line?

```
@commands.command()
    async def scoredetail(self, ctx):
        async with aiosqlite.connect("members.db") as db:
             async with db.execute(
                 'SELECT ALL Punktestand, Klasse, Zeit FROM Mitglieder WHERE ID = ?', (ctx.author.id,))  as cursor:
                result = await cursor.fetchall()
                
                if result is None:
                    await ctx.send("{member} hat noch keine Punkte!")
                    return
            
                         
                await ctx.send(f"Deine Punkte: {result}.")
```

result in DC:

Deine Punkte: [(1, 'TEXT', '22-05-2023 09:25:04'), (1, 'TEXT', '22-05-2023 09:27:09'), (1, 'TEXT', '22-05-2023 09:28:25')].

Look at Youtube, Google, ect

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through `cursor.fetchall()` as it returns `Iterable[Row]`, like so:

```
@commands.command()
    async def scoredetail(self, ctx):
        async with aiosqlite.connect("members.db") as db:
             async with db.execute(
                 'SELECT ALL Punktestand, Klasse, Zeit FROM Mitglieder WHERE ID = ?', (ctx.author.id,))  as cursor:
                result = await cursor.fetchall()
                
                if result is None:
                    await ctx.send("{member} hat noch keine Punkte!")
                    return
                else:    
                    finalResult = ''
                    for row in result:
                        finalResult += f'{row}\n'
            
                         
                await ctx.send(f"Deine Punkte: {finalResult}.")
```

This will make a newline between every row in the result.

[API Reference](https://aiosqlite.omnilib.dev/en/stable/api.html#aiosqlite.cursor.Cursor.fetchall)